# Axios post request not working with Django Rest Framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, django-rest-framework, axios

I am trying to use Axios post to create a user in my Django Rest Framework api.

Currently getting "Request failed with status code 400" when trying to post.

It works perfectly fine in postman.

drfServer.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://example.com'
});
```

AuthContext.js

```
const signup = (dispatch) => async ({ email, password }) => {
    try {
        const response = await drfApi.post('/user/',
            {
                data: {
                    username: email,
                    password: password
                }
            }
        );
        // await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
        // dispatch({ type: 'signin', payload: response.data.token });
        // navigate('Task')
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
        dispatch({ type: 'add_error', payload: 'Something went wrong with sign up' })
    }
};
```

I tried using fetch and it works. But with Axios I am not getting it right.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: In the drf are you able to receive the username and password?

Comment: @AashayAmballi Yes, the account is created

Comment: Are you trying to create a user or log in a user?

Comment: I am trying to first create and then get the token for automatic login.

Comment: 400 error basically comes for the validation error. If you're missing any field then it will throw you the 400 error. Are you doing any validation from the DRF side?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this code.

```
const signup = ({email,password}) => dispatch => {
    return axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "your api url",
        data: { 
          username: email,
          password
        })
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result.data);
         })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
         })
};
```

You can find the axios example code here https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: This is diffinitely the answer I've been looking for. `axios.post` did not work for me, but this way worked.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this :

```js
const response = await drfApi.post('/user/', {
                    username: email,
                    password: password
                   }
                 );
```

As using axios.post will automatically take the 2nd param and make it an object with `data` key